# Django datetimefield, timezonefield and epoch

Tags: django, datetime, django-models, time, timezone

I want to work on a django project that work with time(track time of user), but I don't know to choose datetime field or timezone field or epoch time in an integer field for project model. I worked with all of them and I know we can convert them to each other. My question is for saving time in db, process on time and represent which one is recomended and why? What I need to consider for choosing between them?

Answer (score 1):

The [`DateTimeField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#datetimefield) class would be my choice, since it supports timezones, something a simple [`IntegerField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.IntegerField) will not be able to do. If you don't handle timezones, there's a possibility that your computations will be wrong, and you will not be able to display dates and times that are correctly localized for your users.

Also, since a `DateTimeField` gets you a standard Python [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects), it works well for date computations, especially if you use a library like [arrow](https://github.com/crsmithdev/arrow/) to simplify their handling.

Comment: Dont forget to use `USE_TZ = True` in settings.py and always use `timezone.now()` instead of `datetime.now()` (`from django.utils import timezone`)